# Simplest way to prompt for user input using gjs for a gnome extension

Tags: gnome-shell, gjs

I want to popup a simple text input (single line) dialog in a gnome shell extension. What's the simplest way to do that?

Something like:

```
let userEntry = prompt("What is your name?", "<name>");
```